# How to make dual monitors output the same color?

Tags: multiple-monitors, colors

I have two monitors of different models connected to one video adapter. The color of output is very different.

Is there a way that somehow I could get an ICC for one monitor based on the other? For example I give the tool a photo of both monitors displaying the same simple color, so the tool could compare the color and set the color of the bad one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to get a device like Spyder http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/reviews/profiling/spyder3pro.html 
You can get Express version for something around 100$. It's not that cheap but will give you decent result.

Comment: Yes, a professional device should be the choice. But consider that I rarely use it, and I do not need "exactly the same". So 100$ is expansive.